# Strange behavior with isset() returning true for an Array Key that does NOT exist

Tags: php, arrays, isset

I have the following array called `$fruits`:

```
Array
(
    [response] => Array
        (
            [errormessage] => banana
        )  

    [blah] => Array
        (
            [blah1] => blahblah1
            [blah2] => blahblah2
            [blah3] => blahblah3
            [blah4] => blahblah4
        )  

)
```

Yet when I do:

```
isset($fruits['response']['errormessage']['orange'])
```

It returns **true**!

What on earth would cause such a strange behavior and how can I fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`[n]` is also a way to access characters in a string:

```
$fruits['response']['errormessage']['orange']
==
$fruits['response']['errormessage'][0] // cast to int
==
b (the first character, at position 0) of 'banana'
```

Use `array_key_exists`, possibly in combination with `is_array`.

Answer (score 11):

It just boils down to PHP's crazy type system.

`$fruits['response']['errormessage']` is the string `'banana'`, so you're attempting to access a character in that string by the `['orange']` index.

The string `'orange'` is converted to an integer for the purposes of indexing, so it becomes `0`, as in `$fruits['response']['errormessage'][0]`. The 0th index of a string is the first character of the string, so for non-empty strings it's essentially set. Thus `isset()` returns true.

I don't know what you're trying to do in the first place so I can't offer any "fix" for this. It's by design.

Comment: Use array_key_exists(), Luke.

Comment: @St0rM: True... assuming `$fruits['response']['errormessage']` is supposed to be an array, which clearly it isn't, but *could be* ;)

Comment: what I assume is that he's trying to test the existance of `$fruits['response']['errormessage']['orange']` as a key, and that's the only reason I can think of that can make him amazed by the result. He is expecting `false` because that key does not exists. But I can be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

to fix

```
if (is_array($fruits['response']['errormessage']) 
    && isset($fruits['response']['errormessage']['orange'])) { .. }
```