# Why does this return a string value when there is no such index in the array?

Tags: php, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Strange behavior with isset() returning true for an Array Key that does NOT exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9132715/strange-behavior-with-isset-returning-true-for-an-array-key-that-does-not-exis)

```
$arr = array(
         'application' => array (
            'environment' => 'development',
            'mode_debug' => 1,
            'key' => '123456abcdefg',
            'debug_soft' =>
            'firephp',
            'aaa' => array (
                'bbb' => '111',
                'ccc' => '222',
                'ddd' => array (
                    'eee' => '12345',
                ),
            ),
        ),
        'database' => array (
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'database' => '',
            'username' => '',
            'password' => '',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
        ),
    );


if(isset($arr["application"]["aaa"]["ddd"]["eee"]['out']) && !empty($arr["application"]["aaa"]["ddd"]["eee"]['out'])){
    echo "a";
    echo '<br />';
    var_dump($arr["application"]["aaa"]["ddd"]["eee"]['out']);
}else{
    echo "b";
}
```

returns:

```
a
string(1) "1"
```

but there is no 'out' index in the '$arr' array, so why it returns 'string(1) "1"'?

The manual doesn't help, because it only samples one dimentional array:

```
$a = array ('test' => 1, 'hello' => NULL);

var_dump( isset ($a['test']) );            // TRUE
var_dump( isset ($a['foo']) );             // FALSE
var_dump( isset ($a['hello']) );           // FALSE
```

Comment: Wow, thats completely new to me. i think , its because "out" is being casted "0".

Comment: What we should keep in mind is that `isset()` is not exempt or a workaround for PHPs dynamic typing.

Comment: @mario Thank you for notification, question may duplicated

Comment: @user1063434: Note that duplicate links are foremost for hypertextiness, doesn't make your question less interesting or valid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider this:

```
$str = 'test';
var_dump(isset($str['xxx'])); // true
```

It returns true, because:

- PHP supports `$str[$n]` syntax (to address individual characters of the string)
- when calculating index, it's cast to integer type
- when cast to integer, `"xxx"` is `0`; you're accessing `$str[0]` - the first character of that `$str` string, and it (`t`) is a truthy value.

Note that this (quite weird) behavior of [**isset**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) was fixed in PHP 5.4:

> **5.4.0**: Checking non-numeric offsets of strings now returns FALSE.

Answer (score 2):

It does this because your `eee` index contains a string for a value - and strings can be accessed as arrays. When you use the index `out` in the string, it casts `out` to an integer value of `0`, giving you `$arr["application"]["aaa"]["ddd"]["eee"][0]`, which equals `1`.

You can prevent this by using `is_array()`:

```
if (is_array($arr["application"]["aaa"]["ddd"]["eee"]) && isset($arr["application"]["aaa"]["ddd"]["eee"]['out'])) {
```

Comment: See, `isset` is quite convenient because it fails early - i.e., if any of this `['aaa']['bbb']['ccc']` offsets is not accessible, it'll just return `FALSE`. It's not so great with `is_array`: you have to make sure that two last offsets do exist.

Comment: @raina77ow Yeah, one could use `isset($var['aaa']['bbb']['ccc'])` and *then* `is_array($var['aaa']['bbb']['ccc']['xxx'])`; In the OP's case, the `isset()` was `true` - he just needed to validate that it was an array before treating it as such.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to return the first character '1' of $arr["application"]["aaa"]["ddd"]["eee"] value "12345" even key 'out' is not exist.