# PHP isset for an array element while variable is not an array

Tags: php, isset

```
$a = 'a';
echo isset($a['b']);
```

This code returns 1. Why?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9132715/strange-behavior-with-isset-returning-true-for-an-array-key-that-does-not-exis

Comment: It returns nothing checked on http://writecodeonline.com/php/
But `echo isset($a);` returns 1.

Comment: have you tested your code? `isset($a['b'])` returns false.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

String characters can be referenced by their offset using syntax like $a[0] for the first character, e.g.

```
$string = 'Hello';
echo $string[1];  // echoes 'e'
```

so PHP is recognising that $a is a string; casting your 'b' to a numeric (which casts to a 0), and trying to test isset on $a[0], which is the first character `a`

Though it should also throw an illegal offset 'b' warning if you have errors enabled

**EDIT**

```
$a = 'a';
echo isset($a['b']), PHP_EOL;
echo $a['b'];
```

PHP 5.3

```
1
a
```

PHP 5.4

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'b' in /Projects/test/a10.php on line 6
a
```

PHP 5.5

```
PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'b' in /Projects/test/a10.php on line 6

Warning: Illegal string offset 'b' in /Projects/test/a10.php on line 6
a
```

Comment: @Mark `isset` won`t throw a warning. and as of php 5.4 `Checking non-numeric offsets of strings now returns FALSE.`

Comment: strange, I tested it on PHP 5.4.16 (both windows and linux) no warnings for `echo isset($a['b'])`, just returns false. my error_reporting is set to -1 and display errors is on.

Answer (score 2):

Only for php 5.3:

so lets do it slowly:

```
$a['b'];
```

returns 'a' because b is converted to 0 and $a[0] (the first char of 0 = a)

```
isset($a['b']);
```

return true because $a['b'] is 'a' not null

```
echo true;
```

outputs "1" because true is converted to a string and this to "1".

Comment: Thanks for an explaination. I didn't expect that 'b' will be converted to integer.

Comment: @Christoph you are totally wrong! `isset($a['b']);` returns false not true. Have you tested it before posting your answer?

Comment: @bansi I'm totally right did you test it before posting your comment? I did. (php 5.3.23) Ahh see Mark Baker's answer .. it doesn't work starting with php 5.4

Answer (score 1):

because [ISSET](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) return the 1 if the value is set.

Use it like this :

```
if(isset($a['b']){
echo $a['b'];
}
```

Comment: yes it should, because you have defined $a['b']='a'; No choice there..!!

Comment: Where did I defined $a['b'] = 'a'?

Comment: i mean at the time of execution the b converted to 0 and 0 stands for the first position of your string so the output will be 'a'.

Answer (score 0):

For the same reason as this...

```
echo true;
```

PHP cannot echo a non-string/non-integer so it converts the true into 1 and 0 for false.

Comment: But it doesn't explain yet why it's returning true.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$a = 'a';
var_dump($a);
?>
it will gives output string(1) "a" 
if you will echo $a['b'] it will give you output as a so $a['b'] also has value
hence
<?php
$a = 'a';
echo isset($a['b']);
?>
outputs value 1
```