# PHP : is it dynamich thing or any thing else

Tags: php, arrays, isset

Anyone can explain it why is it true

```
  $a = Array('b' = > 'okokokok');
  if ( isset( $a['b']['ok'] ) ) {
      echo $a['b']['ok']; // Print 0
  } else {
      echo "else";
  }
```

Comment: Are you sure it prints 0 and not a lowercase `o` ?

Comment: I am getting else as the output.

Comment: had this some days ago: short php 5.3 cahnges index 'ok' to 0 and later versions don't.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP isset for an array element while variable is not an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18399372/php-isset-for-an-array-element-while-variable-is-not-an-array)

Comment: @STTLCU : Its a lowercase o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it doesn't print '0', but lowercase 'o'.
Try this:

```
$string = 'abc';
echo $string['omgwhysuchkeyworks'];
```

It will print 'a'. That is because it seems in PHP when you try any key (other than numeric) on string variable it will return the first character of the string. That's also why `isset($a['b']['ok'])` returns true.

And it might be an issue of the PHP version. Perhaps on newer version it will work as intended (it will write 'else')

Comment: Ok ...Let me check it with PHP version

Answer (score 5):

This was for backward compatibility with PHP 4 (see [PHP Bug #29883](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=29883)). When casting a string to an integer, and the string is not a valid integer, it becomes 0 (zero). The letter "o" is printed because that is the character at offset 0 in the string.

In PHP 5.4, the behavior intentionally changed (see [PHP Bug #60362](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=60362)); that PHP version instead prints "else".

Answer (score 1):

It prints `else`. `'ok'` is no array index but a value on index `'b'` of array `$a`:

```
Array
(
    [b] => okokokok
)
```

See http://ideone.com/50EhGW

Comment: this is true only because of your PHP version, which is >= 5.4

Answer (score 1):

```
$a = Array('b' = > 'okokokok');
  if ( isset( $a['b']['ok'] ) ) {
      echo $a['b']['ok']; // Print 0
  } else {
      echo "else";
  }
```

When you have a string ,you can treat it as array. its indexes would be numerical, starting from zero to string length minus one. But if you try to pass a string as index  (**ok** in this case) , PHP tries to convert it to integer , evaluates it as zero(`intval('ok')`). On  systems with php 5.4, it  treat differently and checks the key itself and doesn't do the converting .So, in one system it may print `else` and on the other it prints `o`.