# PHP super weird warning : illigal string offset while creating a key

Tags: php, arrays

I have a very strange problem.
I am running through a foreach loop to compile an array but I receive an error.

I reveive the following warning :

**Warning: Illegal string offset 'clientaccount_id' in**

For this line of code:

```
$this->PreparedData[$table][$field] = 0;
```

I would say this to be logic if I would be doing something like:

$testVariable = $this->PreparedData[$table][$field];

Then the variable **$field** filled with *'clientaccount_id'* would not exist.
But I am CREATING the field 'clientaccount_id' so to ME this is almost impossible to give an error.

**The code**

```
private function AssignData(){
    foreach($this->FieldKeys as $table => $value){
        ///######## IF THE PREPARED DATA ARRAY DOES NOT EXIST
        if(isset($this->PreparedData[$table]) === false){
            ///######## SET THE ARRAY KEY
            $this->PreparedData[$table] = array();
        }
        ///######## RUN THROUGH ALL SET SUB DATA
        foreach($value as $field){
            ///######## IF THE FIELD EXISTS
            if(isset($this->AccountData[$field]) === true){
                ///######## ASSIGN THE DATA
                ///$this->PreparedData[$table][$field] = $this->AccountData[$field];
                ///$this->PreparedData[$field] = $this->AccountData[$field];
                $this->PreparedData[$table][$field] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    exit('GOT THROUGH!!');
}
```

Could anyone see the error I am overlooking?

> **Solved!!**
>
> Thanks to *VMcreator*
>
> Changed :
>
> ```
> isset($this->PreparedData[$table]) === false
> ```
>
> to this:
>
> ```
> is_array($this->PreparedData[$table]) === false
> ```
>
> Please read the explanation below WHY

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to change this line:

```
isset($this->PreparedData[$table]) === false
```

to this:

```
 !is_array($this->PreparedData[$table])
```

**I saw this explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9132715/strange-behavior-with-isset-returning-true-for-an-array-key-that-does-not-exis):**

> It just boils down to PHP's crazy type system.
>
> $fruits['response']['errormessage'] is the string 'banana', so you're
>   attempting to access a character in that string by the ['orange']
>   index.
>
> The string 'orange' is converted to an integer for the purposes of
>   indexing, so it becomes 0, as in
>   $fruits['response']['errormessage'][0]. The 0th index of a string is
>   the first character of the string, so for non-empty strings it's
>   essentially set. Thus isset() returns true.

You might be curious why your situation is comparable to that quoted statement even if **$this->PreparedData[$table]** seems a single dimensional array only, well its not a single dimensional array only, because you are accessing a class object, its just like doing this  $this["PreparedData"][$table].

Comment: You don't know how happy I am with this answer!!
Thanks a million!!

(* need to wait 8 min before accepting this answer *)

Comment: I'm happy to help you, I'll add explanation as to why it happens for future reference

Comment: Updated my answer, hope you got it now brother - have a great day.